# How to disable MySQL's errors?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database with a string for a primary_key, which I set. I need to check frequently if around 1000 "items" exist in that table before adding them, because there must not be any duplicates. The result is 2 queries per Item, or 2000 total, which is 1-2 seconds of extra loading time.

If I try to insert the new row anyway, without checking for duplicates it doesn't get inserted and that's great, but mysql returns an error, which crashes my service.

My questions:

1. Can I turn off those errors?
2. Is there a better way to prevent inserting duplicates than making an extra query?

Comment: If you think my question is bad, please say why.

Comment: yes, fix errors maybe? [insert ignore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: I need the error to go away, nothing else needs fixing.

Comment: If the service is crashing then your code needs fixing! so yes something else does need fixing don't ignore errors fix them.

Comment: If you have a solution, post your answer. I can think of "fix the error" myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`IGNORE` keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) to have duplicates dropped from your inserts:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourTable Values (...)
```

Answer (score 5):

> mysql returns an error, which crashes my service.

it's actually your own code that crashes your service as mysql error cannot crash anything.

> Is there a better way to prevent inserting duplicates

`INSERT IGNORE`